# How to get feedback from user for a very small change

Tags: website-design, feedback

Imagine we want to get feedback from users for just a **color of a button** that they may use in their daily web surfing in my website.
in my mind popping up a textbox and asking for a feedback about that specific small change is a joke and users may even don't notice that change happened.

I read about [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) for getting feedback for UI changes but I'm not really sure this way brings informative feedback about that little change. some users may even doesn't care about the color of that button. people may or may not like the change but they still use that button and using analyzing are going to be useless

I'm thinking about having different theme in website and let users change it for themselves but this seems a lot more work than a small change. what do you think is the best way?

My concern is more about how to get user feedback for this such a little things in a way that users want to tell their opinion. for me things like star rating or so for this kind of things is a bit too much, i seeking for a nice replacement.

Comment: @Big_Chair suggestion is a good idea. You could do A/B testing but it would have to be done without changing anything else, considering all the variables that affect each user and I think you would need a huge amount of tests to be able to take realistic conclusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a change like that is **too small to use analytics tools** on it.
Maybe inviting 5-10 or so people to your office and make a little **test in within-subject design** would be a good alternative to get people's opinion on it.

Comment: Agreed. This way you can find out not only what they like and dislike - but also WHY.

Answer (score 2):

As the designer of the site, you retain the right to control minor details - such as the color of a button. Having a theme switcher can be good in some cases (night mode, for example) but is likely to go unnoticed unless you draw attention to it or automatically switch based on some other user-specific parameter (such as time of day for them). The only way to know if a change is going to be well-received is to make it, then check the results in your analytics.

The point is, if A/B testing doesn't show you anything informative, then chances are that users don't care about the difference between A and B. If they don't care, then you can change it however you like; or otherwise choose to leave it alone.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my concern is more about how to get user feedback for this such a little things in a way that users want to tell their opinion. for me things like star rating or so for this kind of things is a bit too much, i seeking for a nice replacement.

Comment: @MasihAkbari I think that any sort of feedback that requires user interaction is going to be a bit too much for a small change and may actually drive them away from the site. I'm not sure what you were hoping for, but I see no other way than indirect tests (A/B tests, etc.)

Comment: about A/B testing, i thing people may or may not like the change but they still use that button and using analyzing are going to be useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get feedback about small changes on your website. Then you have to do some thing that get the user attention to it.

In your case you want to change button color on your website. Then you have to apply some animation effect that inform to user about for changes made on button. For example you can use blink effect. When user is going to hover the button then immediately you can ask for ratting about changes in popup box on same page.

But you have to do all these things very cleverly. Users must not be bore with all process.
Thank you.